# SVG "vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke" in <marker>: Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: css, svg, vector-graphics, stroke

Consider the following snippet, which contains two versions of an SVG with an arrowhead defined by a `<marker>`. Lines and paths are styled with `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke`. The second version is simply the first version with all coordinates divided by 10 (and the marker `id` changed to something else).

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nkevo5ja

On Windows 10:

- **Firefox** 78.0.2 (64-bit): Arrowheads are the **same** size.
- **Chrome** 84.0.4147.89 (64-bit): Arrowheads are **different** sizes.
  If `vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke` is removed, the arrowheads become the same size (but this breaks the line-width).

Whose implementation is incorrect?

[image: Firefox: same arrowhead size; Chrome: different arrowhead size.]

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <style>
    line, path {
      stroke: black;
      vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
    }
  </style>
</svg>

<!-- Larger version -->
<svg width="120px" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 300">
  <defs>
    <marker id="larger"
      viewBox="0 -20 70 40"
      refX="70" refY="0"
      markerWidth="70" markerHeight="40"
      orient="auto"
    >
      <path d="M 70 0 L 0 -20 L 0 20 z"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1="400" y1="300" x2="0" y2="0" marker-end="url(#larger)"/>
</svg>

<!-- Smaller version (larger version with all coordinates divided by 10) -->
<svg width="120px" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 40 30">
  <defs>
    <marker id="smaller"
      viewBox="0 -2 7 4"
      refX="7" refY="0"
      markerWidth="7" markerHeight="4"
      orient="auto"
    >
      <path d="M 7 0 L 0 -2 L 0 2 z"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1="40" y1="30" x2="0" y2="0" marker-end="url(#smaller)"/>
</svg>
```

Chromium issue: https://crbug.com/1107791

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Firefox has the correct behavior, there is even a note in [the specs](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#MarkerAttributes) about this exact case:</s>

> When ‘markerUnits’ has the value `strokeWidth`, the size of the marker is relative to the stroke-width after it has had any transforms applied that affect the width of the stroke in the user coordinate system for the stroke. This means that, for example, the vector-effect attribute with a value of `non-scaling-stroke` will result in the markers also being non scaling.

`strokeWidth` being the default value for `markerUnits`.

---

**Edit:** Turns out my reading of the specs was wrong and that what should happen is the `markerWidth` and `markerHeight` are multiplied by the final computed `strokewidth` of the stroked line – 1px here – just like Chrome did.

You can refer to [Robert Longson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64192087/3702797), who did push a fix for Firefox so it aligns with Chrome and the specs.

---

Using this exact snippet, you can get the same results in both Chrome and Firefox by setting this `markerUnits` attribute to `userSpaceOnUse`.

```html
<!-- Styles -->
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <style>
    line, path {
      stroke: black;
      vector-effect: non-scaling-stroke;
    }
  </style>
</svg>

<!-- Larger version -->
<svg width="120px" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 300">
  <defs>
    <marker id="larger"
      viewBox="0 -20 70 40"
      refX="70" refY="0"
      markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      markerWidth="70" markerHeight="40"
      orient="auto"
    >
      <path d="M 70 0 L 0 -20 L 0 20 z"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1="400" y1="300" x2="0" y2="0" marker-end="url(#larger)"/>
</svg>

<!-- Smaller version (larger version with all coordinates divided by 10) -->
<svg width="120px" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 40 30">
  <defs>
    <marker id="smaller"
      viewBox="0 -2 7 4"
      refX="7" refY="0"
      markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
      markerWidth="7" markerHeight="4"
      orient="auto"
    >
      <path d="M 7 0 L 0 -2 L 0 2 z"/>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line x1="40" y1="30" x2="0" y2="0" marker-end="url(#smaller)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Excellent! How long should I wait before accepting?

Comment: @user13967316 I don't know, unlike other sites of the network, StackOverflow doesn't have such a soft limit, apart from the one that the checkbox should give you if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox was wrong and I've just fixed it, it now has the same rendering as Chrome for this case.

There are two effects here, non-scaling-stroke on the path within the marker and non-scaling-stroke on the markerWidth that the marker is using. That markerWidth is based on the marked line's stroke-width and that stroke is also non-scaling.

Firefox and Chrome did apply the non-scaling-stroke transform to the marker's lines but only Chrome corrected the strokeWidth too. Firefox nightlies will deal with the strokeWidth correctly from tomorrow. Firefox 83 will be the first release containing the fix.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When the [spec](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/painting.html#MarkerAttributes) says "When ‘markerUnits’ has the value strokeWidth, [...] vector-effect [...] non-scaling-stroke will result in the markers also being non scaling", does the non-scaling not apply to the size of the marker in addition to stroke-width of its path?

Comment: I already explained in my answer, that's talking about the condition where the marker's contents are non-scaling, not the element being marked.

Comment: @RobertLongson but their css applies to both the marker content and the marked line, so I don't get how it matters that there is a distinction here... To be honest I'm not sure to understand clearly your answer's explanation.

Comment: What's the strokeWidth of the non-scaling stroke element. That's what we need to pass to the marker element's renderer and it shouldn't change. That's where Firefox fell down and Chrome succeeded.

Comment: So if I got it right it should be *defined markerWidth* x *marked element's final strokeWidth*, right? Does the edit to my answer makes sense?